# Shiny Update Windows 10 : Failed to load resource img src from local

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a windows 10 with local R/RStudio installed.
A few days again I updated R to v3.5.3 and RStudio to v1.2.1330.
I didn't check my app immediately, only a few days later. Meanwhile I had to install many Julia/Atom-Juno packages for a training and now when I run (locally) an app I'm working on, all the images are gone. 
https://github.com/phileas-condemine/carto_indicateurs
The app looked like that : https://drees.shinyapps.io/Cartographie_des_indicateurs/ (I didn't try to redeploy, even if, being another OS it might still work)

Here is a simple reprex

within app.R (ran within an RStudio project)

```
library(shiny)
download.file(url = "https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray-125.png",
              destfile = "www/rstudio.png",mode = "wb")#I have to add this for windows 10
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$img(src="https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/RStudio-Logo-Blue-Gray-125.png"),
    tags$img(src="rstudio.png")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

The LOCAL image doesn't render, instead I have a broken image. (the one I get from URL is OK)
When I open the Chrome inspector and check the JS console I have the following error

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` rstudio.png:1

I tried to check the reprex with the latest rocker/rstudio image but I can't reproduce it. Probably because it's a Windows 10 related issue.

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics 
[3] grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.3 
 [2] magrittr_1.5   
 [3] R6_2.4.0       
 [4] promises_1.0.1 
 [5] later_0.8.0    
 [6] htmltools_0.3.6
 [7] tools_3.5.3    
 [8] Rcpp_1.0.1     
 [9] jsonlite_1.6   
[10] digest_0.6.18  
[11] xtable_1.8-3   
[12] httpuv_1.5.1   
[13] mime_0.6
```

I tried re-installing R v3.5.3 & latest RStudio v1.2.1335, it doesn't fix it.

What troubles me most is that some of the apps render all the images without any problem.
For example this one works alright : https://github.com/phileas-condemine/trafic_dataviz.drees
Is it because of the dependencies that somehow fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Back to shiny 1.2.0 & R 3.5.2 fixes the problem, all images are displayed correctly. So the "bug" either comes from shiny 1.3.1 or R 3.5.3

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics 
[3] grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bsplus_0.1.1         
 [2] shinycssloaders_0.2.0
 [3] markdown_0.9         
 [4] stringr_1.3.1        
 [5] shinyBS_0.61         
 [6] shinydashboard_0.7.1 
 [7] shinyjs_1.0          
 [8] V8_2.2               
 [9] shinyWidgets_0.4.4   
[10] DT_0.5               
[11] data.table_1.12.0    
[12] dplyr_0.7.8          
[13] shiny_1.2.0          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0      
 [2] pillar_1.3.1    
 [3] compiler_3.5.2  
 [4] later_0.8.0     
 [5] bindr_0.1.1     
 [6] tools_3.5.2     
 [7] digest_0.6.18   
 [8] packrat_0.5.0   
 [9] lubridate_1.7.4 
[10] jsonlite_1.6    
[11] tibble_2.0.1    
[12] pkgconfig_2.0.2 
[13] rlang_0.3.1     
[14] rstudioapi_0.9.0
[15] crosstalk_1.0.0 
[16] yaml_2.2.0      
[17] curl_3.3        
[18] bindrcpp_0.2.2  
[19] htmlwidgets_1.3 
[20] tidyselect_0.2.5
[21] glue_1.3.0      
[22] R6_2.3.0        
[23] purrr_0.3.0     
[24] magrittr_1.5    
[25] scales_1.0.0    
[26] promises_1.0.1  
[27] htmltools_0.3.6 
[28] assertthat_0.2.0
[29] mime_0.6        
[30] xtable_1.8-3    
[31] colorspace_1.4-0
[32] httpuv_1.5.1    
[33] stringi_1.2.4   
[34] munsell_0.5.0   
[35] crayon_1.3.4
```